# Process Sent and Received Messages

Tags: macos, mac, process

I'm using Mac OS X, I noticed 2 columns in Activity Monitor: Sent Msgs & Rcvd Msgs

I was wondering what is the meaning of them and what kind of messages are they, Are they network packets or something else? I noticed some of applications are continuously sending and receiving them should I be concerned?

Comment: Please don't cross post questions. Your other question on Stack Overflow was migrated here and this just causes a mess. In the future, please post your question **once** and don't let people tell you to ask it elsewhere. A question can always be migrated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those numbers refer to Mach messages used to request and receive services from the system kernel.  You'll have to grok [Apple's kernel documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/Mach/Mach.html) to understand which kernel interfaces generate these messages and why.  Unless you do low level system programming there is no reason for you to care about the message count numbers, which is why they aren't displayed by default.

Answer (score 1):

These are messages sent between different running processes on your computer. It is normal for processes to send and receive messages.

It is **not** an indication of network traffic.