# Process Sent and Received Messages

Tags: macos, process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Process Sent and Received Messages](https://superuser.com/questions/422170/process-sent-and-received-messages)

I'm using Mac OS X, I noticed 2 columns in Activity Monitor:
Sent Msgs & Rcvd Msgs

I was wondering what is the meaning of them and what kind of messages are they, Are they network packets or something else?
I noticed some of applications are continuously sending and receiving them should I be concerned?

Comment: I feel like that may have been sarcastic, if not disregard this but Stack Overflow is for programming related questions, whereas superuser is geared towards questions about the advanced usage of your computer.

Comment: I'm a programmer and I was interested to know what could cause that messages. I thought it might be something from sockets or maybe pipes.